# Magento Security Updates - Can't Get Help

Tags: magento-enterprise, patches

I've been trying to contact Magento for the last month and have had no success. We have Enterprise, but there I cannot find the area Magento recommends for downloading the security updates:

Navigate to Download Tab (Where? I have never seen this tab)

Magento Enterprise Edition > Support Patches (Can't find this)

It then says if you can't download request by making a support ticket. When I click on the support ticket area it takes me to my account and does nothing.

Please assist in any way possible. Is there a Magento Support Email I can use directly or a number or suggestions as to why all of this is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Once logged into the Partner section you need to select the menu item `Technical Resources`. Then on this page at the bottom left of the page there is a section called `Enterprise Edition` which has a download link.

This page will show you an explorer that contains all the EE based downloads including patches. Under the section called `Patches & Support` you will see all the available patches for different versions of Magento.

Answer (score 0):

Try contacting Ben Marks on Twitter, he is always around. This question will be probably removed since this is not the place to ask for official support, but I think Ben might be able to help you or at least direct you. https://twitter.com/benmarks/